# jQuery isotope inside tab/accorion

Tags: tabs, accordion, jquery-isotope

I am trying to run a 4 column masonry isotope item inside a tab/accordion. I found that I will need to use the `layout`, to make the isotope work, when tab element is visible.

So I tried this;

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.tab_title').click(function(){
        $('.iso-container').isotope({
            itemSelector : '.iso-item',
            layoutMode:'masonry',
            masonry:{
                columnWidth: 300
            }       
        });

    });
});
```

When I click the tab (.tab_title), isotope appears, but in one column, taking entire container width. How can I solve this?

To mention, I have tried `$('.iso-container').isotope('layout')` as well. This also shows one item taking entire width of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using:

```
$('.iso-container').isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope( { sortBy: 'original-order' } );
```

If in case, images are overlapping on each other, use [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/).

```
var $grid = $('.iso-container').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $grid.isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
});
```